# I would like to know how this code can be rewritten as an IF statement?

Tags: c++

```
mcPlayerTurn = (mcPlayerTurn == 'W') ? 'B' : 'W';
```

I am making a game of two players and after one player another player's turn comes.

Comment: Recommendation: Take a shot at solving this yourself and ask targeted questions about your attempt if you have problems.

Comment: See [Conditional or Ternary Operator (?:) in C/C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/conditional-or-ternary-operator-in-c-c/).

Comment: Why? It's better the way it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [Conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) on cppreference.com:

> The conditional operator expressions have the form
>
> `E1 ? E2 : E3`
>
> The first operand of the conditional operator is evaluated and contextually converted to `bool`. After both the value evaluation and all side effects of the first operand are completed, if the result was `true`, the second operand is evaluated. If the result was `false`, the third operand is evaluated.

So, the statement `mcPlayerTurn = (mcPlayerTurn == 'W') ? 'B' : 'W';` means:

- If `mcPlayerTurn` is equal to `'W'`, assign `'B'` to `mcPlayerTurn`
- Otherwise, assign `'W'` to `mcPlayerTurn`.

That would look like the following as an `if` statement:

```cpp
if (mcPlayerTurn == 'W')
    mcPlayerTurn = 'B';
else
    mcPlayerTurn = 'W';
```

Comment: @Peter I think you meant `if (mcPlayerTurn != 'W') mcPlayerTurn = 'W'` instead. But, this will only toggle `mcPlayerTurn` to `W` if it is currently `B`, but the OP also needs the reverse logic too, to toggle to `B` when currently `W`. With yr way, you would need 2 `if`s to cover that.